# What are the semantics of the last expression in a block of scala code?

Tags: scala

Following code does not work if I don't uncomment the commented line.It says

**type mismatch; found : Unit required: Option[String]**

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper

object PdfToText {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val filename = "D:\\Scala\\DATA\\HelloWorld.pdf"
    getTextFromPdf(filename) 
  }
  def getTextFromPdf(filename: String): Option[String] = {
    val pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename))
    println(new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf))
    // Some(new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf))
  }
}
```

Code executes fine if I keep the line -

> Some(new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf))

Output:

```
Welcome 
to 
The World of Scala
```

Could anyone please explain the behaviour of the line

" Some(new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a method is the result of the final line of code. `println` returns `Unit`. If that's the last line then that's what the method returns, which conflicts with the stated `Option[String]` return type.

The code `new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf)` returns a `String` and wrapping it in `Some()` makes it an `Option[String]` which does match the stated method return type.

**explanation**

Here is a method that compiles.

```
def six(): Int = {  // takes no arguments and returns an Int
  println("top")    // string sent to stdout
  6                 // this is the Int it returns
}
```

Here is a method that does **not** compile.

```
def six(): Int = {  // takes no arguments and returns an Int
  6                 // this is the Int it should return
  println("end")    // Error: type mismatch
}
```

This method is *supposed* to return an `Int` (that's what the `: Int` means) but the last line is a `println()` statement and `println` returns a `Unit`, not an `Int`, so that causes the error. This method is trying to return `Unit` when it is *supposed* to return `Int`.

This is a very basic concept in the Scala language.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I have just modified my code as follows.    val content=new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf)
    println(content)
    Some(content)
    println(content)    I am wondering in that case why lastline is not working

Comment: What do you mean "lastline is not working"? The output is not what you expect, or the code doesn't compile? If it doesn't compile, is it a new error message? If it's the same old error message then it's probably the same problem with the last line not matching the expected result type.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, My updated function is as follows 

def getTextFromPdf(filename: String): Option[String] = {
    val pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
  val content=new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf) ; println(content);//print step 1   Some(content) ;println(content) ; //print step 2}
 If wrapping is done to make Option[String] using "Some(content)"  then why I see the same error for  "println(content)  //print step 2". Apologies for my limited knowledge. Pls help me to clarify the concept. or you may recommend any URL or book. Appreciate your time and effort. Kind regards

Comment: Thank you very much for detail explanation. I should be more careful before posting such kind of idiotic question. As I told my function to return Option[String] and I code to return Unit.

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is a Scala type that represents the presence or absence of a value. Instead of runtime constructs like `null` and exceptions which have significant downsides, `Option` (and equivalent constructs in other languages) allows for *compile-time* checking that you are handling both possibilities.

A common use of `Option` is a database lookup by id. It is quite possible there is no entity with that id. The return type of the function in Scala would be `Option[Employee]`. If you find one, it would return `Some(employee)`; otherwise simply `None`. Both subclass `Option`. Note that you can think of `Option` like a container of zero or one element.

In your case, you have defined your function to return `Option[String]`, which is why returning `Some(String)` containing the text of the file makes the compiler happy. I hope that answers your question.

Please note though that your function isn't really designed in a way that uses `Option` effectively since there is no issue of presence/absence--just always present. In other words, returning an `Option` isn't useful here. However, it would be perfectly appropriate to use `Option` to represent the cases where the file is or isn't available on the file system to be read.

For example:

```
object PdfToText {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val filename = "D:\\Scala\\DATA\\HelloWorld.pdf"
    val text = getTextFromPdf(filename)
    val result = text.map(t => s"File contents: ${t}").getOrElse("Empty file")
    println(result)
  }

  def getTextFromPdf(filename: String): Option[String] = {
    val file = new File(filename)
    if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory) {
      val pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename))
      Some(new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdf))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```

Here presence is defined by the existence of a readable file, which allows me to return its contents in a `Some`, and absence is defined by the nonexistence of the file or the file being a directory, which manifests as a `None`

I then account for both possibilities in `main`. If there's text to be read because the function gave me back a `Some`, I call `map` (which only fires on `Some`s) to transform the text into a different string. If I get `None`, we skip over to the `getOrElse` and produce a default string.

Either way, we print out whatever we got, which is guaranteed to be a `String` no matter what happened with the original `File`.

As a shameless plug, you can learn more about `Option` in our tutorial [Nine Reasons to Try Scala](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbZ6GzR8B7I). Just fast forward to 8:36.

Comment: Thank you for details on "Option" and guiding me to write decent way to use "Option".

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote so others can also learn in the future.